# Intercept or get callbacks on Google Drive file save and open in addon/apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace, gsuite-addons

I want to build and AddOn for Google Drive that does extra pre-processing/decoration of files when they are uploaded and before opened/downloaded. E.g. add/verify digital signature, call 3rd party service passing file metadata, convert to different mime type, encrypt/decrypt certain files with custom key that's generated by 3rd party service.
I looked through all APIs and don't find any feature that allows to intercept file uploads/downloads and do pre-processing (e.g. intercept uploaded content, reading it as blob, do processing, then save it to Google Drive folder, later when user downloads file, do pre-processing/verification again on file contents and return end result) in a way that's transparent to user.

Another possibility in case intercepting the content would be to try intercept the file selection/upload event and change file extension or path to temp folder, then triggering processing script and saving result to original destination.

I prefer to avoid proxying file uploads/downloads via my custom backend, doing all required processing in context of addon/apps script.

I got a bit confused of how AppsScript GSUite Drive API (File, Folder, Drive classes) relates to Google Drive v2 API with Changes.watch(), Channels, etc...
Is latter intended for backend use only? 
I can't see any notion of events/callbacks provided by AppsScript API, that in theory should be running my addon in context of current user.

I wish I would be abler to ask more concrete question here on API, but currently I struggling to understand how to do basic hooks for my addon to operate on files.

Comment: DriveApp service has it's own set of methods, if you want to use Drive API requests, you can use the Drive [Advance Google Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). Latest Drive API version is [v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v3versusv2). You're able to set the mime type when uploading the file, [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) you can check examples of the different upload types. You can add custom properties to a file as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties).

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: But how do I watch folders to be able to intercept when files are uploaded/modified?

Comment: And how do I intercept file downloading to process it's contents before I return it to user?

Comment: You can't intercept them. With a [Drive Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/drive-addons) you can only trigger functions when the user enters Drive's homepage or when the user select a file(s). With the API you can [watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch) when a file is modified  in order to get a notification, but this will be after the change is made without intercepting the change process.

Comment: Ok. It's clear now. So if I know that user selected a file he wants to open, can I load this file as blob, do processing, save it to temp folder and then redirect user to it?

Comment: Yes. But to redirect it, the user must click a button in the Add-on card. The trigger function will prompt a `Card` object where you can have button with different actions like open a link. [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/drive/building-drive-interfaces#drive_contextual_interface_for_items_selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't intercept them. With a [Drive Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/drive-addons) you can only trigger functions when the user enters Drive's homepage or when the user select a file(s). With the API you can [watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch) when a file is modified in order to get a notification, but this will be after the change is made without intercepting the change process.

If you use a [OnItemsSelectedTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/drive-addons#onitemsselectedtrigger), you need to prompt/return a [Card](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card) when the user selects a file(s), in this card you can set buttons that when clicked by the user it can trigger different [actions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action).